# Chrome extension window.history fails...but why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is totally throwing me for a loop. The idea here is that I need to disable the ability for the context-menu to work on certain machines here at work. **The problem is that when I click the forward and back handlers in my context-menu, the page remains unchanged except when attempting to go forward, the URL gets appended with a '#'..**

I ran the following test:

Opened Chrome dev tools on a tab that had some back navigation history and switched to the dev tools Console tab.

I typed:

`window.history.back()` -- page went back to previous page just fine.
`window.history.forward()` -- page went forward to last page just fine.

Then I switched the context at the top of the Console frame from `<top frame>` to the extension entry 'chrome-extension://abcd...' for my extension.

I typed:

`window.history.back()` -- page went back to previous page just fine.
`window.history.forward()` -- page went forward to last page just fine.

However, the buttons in my extension with accompanying code does not work. I'd love to get some feedback on why this might be happening.

Now one other interesting tidbit of goodness that might help someone to a clue to what may be going on:

I closed and re-opened Chrome fresh, and ran the window.history method tests (from above) in the console. The methods work correctly as expected. Then I attempted, once again, to test the new context menu handler I wrote, which continue to fail. HOWEVER; Right after these tests, if I attempt to run `history.back` methods in the console again, they now fail.

Tested with the same steps after disabling *all* other extensions and restarting the browser with the same results.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Disable Context Menu",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Disabled context menu items for thin clients",
    "permissions": ["contextMenus","tabs"],
    "icons" : {"16": "/icons/printer.png",
               "16": "/icons/reload.png",
               "16": "/icons/back.png",
               "16": "/icons/forward.png"},
    "web_accessible_resources": ["/icons/printer.png","/icons/reload.png",
                                 "/icons/back.png","/icons/forward.png"],
    "content_scripts": [{ 
                           "matches" : ["<all_urls>"],
                           "js" : ["/js/jquery.js","/js/jquery.contextmenu.js","/js/content.js"],
                           "css" : ["/css/jquery.contextmenu.css","/css/menu.css"]
                       }]
}
```

**content.js**

```
function showPrintDialog()
{
    window.print();
}

$().ready(
    function()
    {
        $('body')
            .contextPopup(
            {
                title: 'Generic Context Menu',
                items: 
                [
                    {label: "forward", 
                     icon: chrome.extension.getURL('/icons/forward.png'),
                     action: function(){history.forward()},
                    },
                    {label: "back", 
                     icon: chrome.extension.getURL('/icons/back.png'),
                     action: function(){function(){history.back()},
                    },
                    {label: "reload", 
                     icon: chrome.extension.getURL('/icons/reload.png'),
                     action: function(){window.location.reload(true)}},
                     null,
                    {label: "print", 
                     icon: chrome.extension.getURL('/icons/printer.png'), 
                     action: function(){showPrintDialog()}},
                ],
            });
    });
```

Comment: What would `history` accomplish in a background page context?

Comment: I asked the same question. Like I said, I tried history in the content page first and it failed, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug on the jQuery [`simple-context-menu` plugin](https://github.com/joewalnes/jquery-simple-context-menu) you are using. Replace the line:

```
row.find('a').click(function () { item.action(e); });
```

by:

```
row.find('a').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); item.action(e); });
```

Without adding `preventDefault()`, the click on the menu causes the browser to navigate to the current url with an appended `#`, and that interferes with your intended `history` operations.

Comment: I never would have thought it was a bug in the library! You ROCK!! Thank you!